# Make an HTA file run as admin (elevated)

Tags: jscript, hta, wsh, elevated-privileges

In wsf, vbs and js files you can easily find out if they run elevated and if not you can easily make them.
The code I've written for that is this:

```
EnsureElevatedPrivileges();
WScript.Echo("Running elevated now!");

function EnsureElevatedPrivileges() {
    if (!WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate")) {
        new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(WScript.FullName, "\"" + WScript.ScriptFullName + "\" /elevate", "", "runas", 1);
        WScript.Quit();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work in HTA files because the global WScript variable doesn't exist there.
So how can I force a specific HTA file run (itself) as admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at this : [Procedure to run HTA elevated](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/procedure-to-run-HTA-308b5995)

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>HTA Helpomatic</title> 

<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="oHTA" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTAHelpomatic" 
     SCROLL="yes" 
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" 
> 
<!-- ID="objHTAHelpomatic" --> 
<!-- WINDOWSTATE="maximize" --> 

</head> 

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 

If HTAElevate() = True Then 
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mmc.exe compmgmt.msc", , True 
    Call Main() 
End If 

Sub Main() 
    MsgBox "HTA-Ende", 4096 
End Sub 


'*** v13.3 *** www.dieseyer.de ***************************** 
Function HTAElevate() 
'*********************************************************** 
' Unter Windows x64 laufen VBS' nach einem Doppelklick in der x64-Umgebung 
' mit %WinDi%\System32\wscript.exe oder mit %WinDi%\System32\cscript.exe. 
' In der x64-Umgebung laufen VBS aber nicht (richtig). Die Prozedur 
' HTAElevate() erkennt dies und startet ggf. das VBS in der 

  Const Elev = " /elevated" 

' MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5016 :: " 

' Trace32Log "5018 :: oHTA.commandLine: ==" & oHTA.commandLine & "==", 1 

  HTAElevate = True 

' If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5022 :: " 
  If InStr( LCase( oHTA.commandLine ), Elev) > 0 then Exit Function 


  On Error Resume Next 
    window.resizeto 750, 10 ' : window.moveto screen.width / 2, screen.height / 2 
  On Error GoTo 0 

' MsgBox oHTA.commandLine, , "5030 :: " 

  createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", oHTA.commandLine & Elev, "", "runas", 1 

  HTAElevate = False 

  self.close 

End Function ' HTAElevate() 


</SCRIPT> 
<body> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Here is a more compact version similar to the original VBS code:
`If InStr(LCase(oHTA.commandLine), " /elevated") <= 0 Then
 CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", oHTA.commandLine & " /elevated", "", "runas", 1 
 self.close
End If`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" use="to move window offscreen so that it should not flicker">
        X=top.screenleft
        Y=top.screentop
        window.moveTo -2000,-2000
    </SCRIPT>
    <hta:application
      ID="thisHta"
      ApplicationName="The Great ManojBhakarPCM"
      Border="thin"
      BorderStyle="Static"
      Caption="Yes"
      ContextMenu="No"
      MaximizeButton="No"
      MinimizeButton="No"
      Navigable="No"
      Scroll="yes"
      Selection="yes"
      ShowInTaskbar="Yes"
      SingleInstance="no"
      SysMenu="Yes"
      WindowState="normal"
    >
    <SCRIPT Language="VBScript" use="to Run As Administrator And window onload.">
        If InStr(LCase(thisHta.commandLine), " /elevated") = 0 Then
            createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "mshta.exe", thisHta.commandLine & " /elevated", "", "runas", 4
            self.close
        else
            window.moveTo X,Y
        End If
        Sub Window_OnLoad 'On window loading elements compeleted. start work here.
          Document.body.innerHtml = "hello public, to kaise hai aap log? तो कैसे है आप लोग ?"
        End Sub
    </SCRIPT>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"  />
</head>

<style>
    /* Author: ManojBhakarPCM */
    body {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .tile{/* Tile: width:vary, height: content wrap, padding: 5px;*/
        height: auto !important;
        padding:10px;
        margin:3px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .tilehead{
        height: auto !important;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        padding-top:2px;
        padding-bottom:2px;
        margin:2px;
        font-size:10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    /*-----COLORS----*/
    .pink{background-color:#FF4081;color:white;}
    .red{background-color:#D32F2F;color:white;}
    .purple{background-color:#E040FB;color:white;}
    .deeppurple{background-color:#512DA8;color:white;}
    .indigo{background-color:#536DFE;color:white;}
    .blue{background-color:#1976D2;color:white;}
    .lightblue{background-color:#0288D1;color:white;}
    .cyan{background-color:#00BCD4;color:white;}
    .teal{background-color:#00796B;color:white;}
    .green{background-color:#388E3C;color:white;}
    .lime{background-color:#CDDC39;color:white;}
    .yellow{background-color:#FFEB3B;color:white;}
    .darkyellow{background-color:#FBC02D;color:white;}
    .orange{background-color:#FF5722;color:white;}
    .bluegray{background-color:#607D8B;color:white;}
    .gray{background-color:#333;color:white;}
    
    .roundcorner{border-radius:5px;}
    .bold{font-weight:bold;}
    .padmin{padding:5px;}
    .padmid{padding:10px;}
    .padfull{padding:15px;}
    .inline{display:inline-block;}
    /* --------CONTROLS---------*/
    /*NAVBAR*/
    
    .navbar {overflow: hidden;background-color: #333;padding:3px;text-decoration: none;}
    .navbar a{padding:5px;font-size: 10px;text-decoration: none;}
    .navbar a:hover{background-color:red;}

    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 50%;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
</style> 
<body> 

Hellow Worlds
</body> 
</html>
```

I have created this hta templet and i use it very often. I belive that templets are best way to work with scripting etc. i usually keep uploaded these templets to websites so when working on any computer(which is not mine) can do work done just by downloading and start coding.
FEATURES:

- Run as administrator
- Does Not Flicker.
- Don't Even Show Before getting admin prev.
- Unicode support.
- All HTA tags.
- usefull classes of css for smooth UI